# Is there a list of RTCPeerConnection Objects

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am running some RTC in Javascript (on Chrome) and I would like to be able to see all the open RTCPeerCOnnections (Or any that are in any live state).   Obviously I can list them as created, but I wondered if there was somewhere I could find a collection of them.  It strikes me they are not in the DOM anywhere nor are they in window.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 5):

There is no standard way. You might try to override the peerconnection constructor along the lines of [this](https://github.com/opentok/rtcstats/blob/master/rtcstats.js#L110) and [this](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/webrtcnotify/blob/master/snoop.js).